# Using Keycloak as OIDC server for both web and mobile clients

Tags: playframework, keycloak, openid-connect, appauth

I'm playing with a project that has the following configuration:

- Keycloak as OIDC server
- Play framework with Pac4J as security library and Pac4J-Play as an interface
- Mobile iOS client with AppAuth as OIDC adapter

When dealing with API through web interface – everything is OK. Pac4J-Play checks Play session for active OIDC profile, if it's not there user will get redirected to OIDC login flow provided by Keycloak. Successful auth brings user back to web interface with Play session having correct information so that all future API calls are permitted.

I have a problem organizing interactions from mobile client. AppAuth allows obtaining access, refresh and id tokens correctly but I don't know how to integrate them with Pac4J auth. I'm currently playing with accepting tokens from mobile in a separate API call and trying to hack Pac4J to wrap those as if they were obtained through Pac4J. However, it feels like a hack and there is some established practice of having this web/mobile/API/OIDC setup the right way that I'm not following.

Another question to the same problem is whether I should be using separate Keycloak clients for API and mobile authorizations. E.g. will access token obtained through "mobile" client configured in Keycloak work with calls governed by "web" Keycloak client?

Thanks

Comment: You must use different client for API and mobile as they won't use the same auth flow